# Center text vertically and horizontally without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, center

**First of all, it's different from others questions** because I can't use `position: absolute;` as I used usually because of my jQuery plugin (I don't use this plugin in the example, but I have to do `position: relative;` to the inside-table).

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/h8ywumbk/

*HTML:*

```
<div id="table">
  <div id="inside-table" >
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#inside-table {
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#inside-table span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I'm trying to center the text (**not a single line**) vertically and horizontally on the tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `flexbox`

```css
#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#inside-table {
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#inside-table span {
  
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="inside-table">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Im using WEBMATRIX and it shows me an errors message to display:flex and the next two lines...

Comment: Hm.. I don't know what is it, but it should be ashamed that it did not know about flexbox :)

Comment: it still shows the messages, but somehow it center the text on my website although it. Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="table">
  <div class="td">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="td">
    <img alt="" src="http://url style="width: 120px; height: 148px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it centered like this:

```
#inside-table span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

You can always mess with the percentages if you want it shifted one direction or another